# Consider Van der Pol’s equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

1. Consider Van der Pol’s equation:

$$y''-0.2(1-y^2)y'+y=0, \quad y(0)= 0.1, \quad y'(0)=0.1$$

(i) Find the approximate solution for this problem using the Taylor series method.  Your expansion should include the first three non-zero terms and you should work to six decimal places accuracy. First find the approximate solutions for both  y (0.1)  and  y’ (0.1)  using the first three non-zero terms of Taylor series expansion for each function and then use this information to calculate the approximate solution at  x = 0.2.

(ii)   Consider the following finite difference method for solving

```
Is this method zero stable ?
```

.      Examine the stability of this method for non-zero (but small) h  if it is applied to the test
    equation :
$$   y ' = λ y$$

Comment: (ii) Consider the following finite difference method for solving

 Y’= f(x,y) , y (x0 )=yo   :

Y n+2 =4yn+1 -5yn = h (4 fn+1 +2 fn)

Comment: Dear amzoti, this part was missing

Comment: @ Amzoni : No we don't.. all it says is dat it's a non zero but small term

Comment: This is the third repetition of the same homework question. (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/685280/consider-van-der-pols-equation) Editing and adding to your original question will keep it up in the queue, no need for reposts.

Answer (score 2):

We are given the Van der Pol equation:

$$\tag 1 y''- 0.2(1-y^2)y'+ y = 0, \quad y(0)= 0.1, \quad y'(0)=0.1$$

$(i)$: The Taylor series about a points $x = a$, is given by:

$ \tag 2 f(a) + \dfrac{f'(a)}{1!} (x-a)  + \dfrac{f''(a)}{2!} (x-a)^2 + \dfrac{f^{(3)}(a)}{3!} (x-a)^3 + \ldots + \dfrac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!} (x-a)^n$

For this problem, $a = 0$, hence:

$$ \tag 3 y(0) + \dfrac{y'(0)}{1!} (x)  + \dfrac{y''(0)}{2!} (x)^2 + \ldots +$$

We have:

- $y(0) = 0.1$
- $y'(0) = 0.1$
- $y''(0) =  0.2(1-y(0)^2)y'(0)- y(0) = 0.2(1- (0.1)^2) 0.1 - 0.1 = -0.0802$

Using the first three nonzero terms of $(3)$ yields the Taylor series about $x = 0$ of:

$$\tag 4 y(x) = y(0) + \dfrac{y'(0)}{1!} (x)  + \dfrac{y''(0)}{2!} (x)^2 = 0.1 + 0.1x - \dfrac{0.0802x^2}{2!} = 0.1 + 0.1x - 0.0401x^2$$

The derivative of $(4)$ is:

$$\tag 5 y'(x) = 0.1 - 0.0802x$$

We can now find:

- $y (0.1) = 0.1 + 0.1(0.1) - 0.0401(0.1)^2 = 0.109599$
- $y'(0.1) = 0.1 - 0.0802(0.1) = 0.091980$
- $y''(0.1) = 0.2(1-y(0.1)^2)y'(0.1)- y(0.1) = 0.2(1- (0.109599)^2) 0.091980 - 0.109599 = -0.091424$

Now the Taylor expansion about $x = 0.1$ is:

$$\tag 6 y(x) = y(0.1) + \dfrac{y'(0.1)}{1!} (x-0.1)  + \dfrac{y''(0.1)}{2!} (x-0.1)^2 = 0.109599 + 0.091980(x-0.1) - \dfrac{0.091424(x-0.1)^2}{2!}$$

At $x = 0.2$, the approximation $(6)$ yields:

$$y(0.2) = 0.109599 + 0.091980(0.2-0.1) - \dfrac{0.091424(0.2-0.1)^2}{2!} = 0.118340$$

$(ii)$: Please show your work.

Comment: Amzoti are you good at differential equation my dear.. if you can help me sort out a questiom on Euler's and Runge kutta?? Pleaaaaaaaase